Deserialize and serialize ZonedDateTime fields in shared objects between controller based on which controller it is used as a parameter for?
I have this Object, which has a field that is a ZonedDateTime:
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
public class TestObject {

    private ZonedDateTime testTime;

    public ZonedDateTime getTestTime() {
        return testTime;
    }

    public void setTestTime(ZonedDateTime testTime) {
        this.testTime = testTime;
    }

}

And two different controller where endpoints use the same object:
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/web")
@Import(ControllerWebConfiguration.class)
public class ControllerWeb {

    @PostMapping("/example")
    public ResponseEntity<String> example(@RequestBody TestObject testObject) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testObject.toString());
    }
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/mobile")
@Import(ControllerMobileConfiguration.class)
public class ControllerMobile {

    @PostMapping("/example")
    public ResponseEntity<String> example(@RequestBody TestObject testObject) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testObject.toString());
    }
}

They both use slightly different "deserialize" for their ZonedDateTime:
public class ZonedDateTimeDeserializerWeb extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);

        String dateTimeString = node.asText();

        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX"));

    }
}

public class ZonedDateTimeDeserializerMobile extends JsonDeserializer<ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);

        String dateTimeString = node.asText();

        return ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"));

    }
}


@Configuration
public class ControllerWebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapperWeb() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule moduleWeb = new SimpleModule();
        moduleWeb.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeDeserializerWeb());
        objectMapper.registerModule(moduleWeb);

        return objectMapper;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class ControllerMobileConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapperMobile() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        SimpleModule moduleMobile = new SimpleModule();
        moduleMobile.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeDeserializerMobile());
        objectMapper.registerModule(moduleMobile);

        return objectMapper;
    }

}

I have tried the above solution but Springboot does not allow two objectMapper beans; Is there any way to achieve what I want?
Thanks in advance!

What do you mean " Springboot does not allow two objectMapper beans"  Spring has no control over what objects you instantiate.   Also why are you creating your own object mappers?   The Spring context will provide one to you that you can auto wire in.

By " Springboot does not allow two objectMapper beans" I mean that I can't start my application for this error: MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found: objectMapperMobile, objectMapperWeb. Will autowiring spring provided bean allow me to have different serialization based on controller?

As explained in this answer, under the hood Spring uses a single MessageConverter which in turn uses the primary ObjectMapper. So you can't just have multiple deserializer beans of the same class using the @Primary and @Qualifier annotations, as is shown in this Baeldung tutorial, as it will not work.
You can use the solution provided in the linked answer, but I think it is not worth the hassle in your case. I would just replace the TestObject with an interface that defines the getter/setter, and implement the interface in a WebTestObject and a MobileTestObject, each one with a field annotated with an hint for Jackson, for example using @JsonSerialize or Spring @DateTimeFormat.
public interface TestObject {

    ZonedDateTime getTestTime();
    void setTestTime(ZonedDateTime testTime);

}

@Getter @Setter
public class WebTestObject implements TestObject {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssX")
    private ZonedDateTime testTime;

}

@Getter @Setter
public class MobileTestObject implements TestObject {

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
    private ZonedDateTime testTime;

}

@Controller
public class Controller {

    @PostMapping("/mobile/example")
    public ResponseEntity<String> mobileExample(@RequestBody MobileTestObject testObject) {
        //in your business logic you can then just use the TestObject interface
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testObject.toString());
    }

    @PostMapping("/web/example")
    public ResponseEntity<String> webExample(@RequestBody WebTestObject testObject) {
        //in your business logic you can then just use the TestObject interface
        return ResponseEntity.ok(testObject.toString());
    }
}


would this approach let me define both deserialize and serialize separately?

if I remember correctly, the annotation is used both for serialization and deserialization; might be worth to separate the request and the response objects...
